# Tag info pages alignment off

Tags: bug, tags

If you go to a tag info (synonym or top users) page, the alignment on the lefthand side is slightly off:

[image]

[image]

[adobe-illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/transparency/synonyms), [transparency](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/transparency/synonyms) etc.

---

Confirmed on:

- Google Chrome 68.0.3440.106
- Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0
- Firefox Quantum 61.0.2

all on Windows 10, 64 bit.